# minecraft auth servers returning down constantly

Tags: java, windows, minecraft

this is a weird one, but with the inspection I have done, I can't figure out what is going on. A client of mine was complaining that their pc was not letting them connect to minecraft, feeling slightly obligated, I went to try to help them. It is returning the error: "unable to reach authentication servers" when attempting to join a server. No, the auth servers are not down as he could connect from another pc. I disabled the firewall thinking it was something blocking the ip, but no dice. I disabled third party antivirus as well and tried reinstalling mc with no avail. If anyone has had experience with this, help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are so many things that could be going on that it's almost impossible to assist you to solve this with the information given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server may be under DDOS attack. If this the case, you can either wait it out, or find a new Minecraft server to connect to.